# Score totals adding incorrectly javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm a noob, so thanks in advance for your help...

When I test my "rock, paper, scissors" javascript game, the "Player vs. Computer" scores seem all over the map. The final score always results in the player or computer winning by 5, but the log of each match shows the scores increasing and decreasing in very random increments.

What did I do wrong?

```
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*   Provided Code - Please Don't Edit   */
////////////////////////////////////////////////
'use strict';

function getInput() {
    console.log("Please choose either 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors'.");
    return prompt("Please choose either 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors'.");
}
function randomPlay() {
    var randomNumber = Math.random();
    if (randomNumber < 0.33) {
        return "rock";
    } else if (randomNumber < 0.66) {
        return "paper";
    } else {
        return "scissors";
    }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*           Write Your Code Below            */
////////////////////////////////////////////////


function getPlayerMove(move) {
    // Write an expression that operates on a variable called `move`
    // If a `move` has a value, your expression should evaluate to that value.
    // However, if `move` is not specified / is null, your expression should equal `getInput()`.
    return move = getInput();
}

function getComputerMove(move) {
    // Write an expression that operates on a variable called `move`
    // If a `move` has a value, your expression should evaluate to that value.
    // However, if `move` is not specified / is null, your expression should equal `randomPlay()`.
    return move = randomPlay();
}

function getWinner(playerMove,computerMove) {
    var winner;
    // Write code that will set winner to either 'player', 'computer', or 'tie' based on the values of playerMove and computerMove.
    // Assume that the only values playerMove and computerMove can have are 'rock', 'paper', and 'scissors'.
    // The rules of the game are that 'rock' beats 'scissors', 'scissors' beats 'paper', and 'paper' beats 'rock'.
    /* YOUR CODE HERE */
    if(playerMove == computerMove) {
        winner = "tie";
    }
    else if(playerMove == "rock" && computerMove == "scissors") {
        winner = "player";
    }
    else if(playerMove == "rock" && computerMove == "paper") {
        winner = "computer";
    }
    else if(playerMove == "paper" && computerMove == "rock") {
        winner = "player";
    }
    else if(playerMove == "paper" && computerMove == "scissors") {
        winner = "computer";
    }
    else if(playerMove == "scissors" && computerMove == "paper") {
        winner = "player";
    }
    return winner;
}

function playToFive() {
    console.log("Let's play Rock, Paper, Scissors");
    var playerWins = 0; 
    var computerWins = 0;

        while (playerWins <= 5 && computerWins <= 5) {
            var playerTurnMove = getPlayerMove();
            var computerTurnMove = getComputerMove();
            var winnerRound = getWinner(playerTurnMove, computerTurnMove);      
            console.log("Player's move is " + playerTurnMove + " Computer's move is " + computerTurnMove);
            console.log("The winner this round is " + winnerRound);
            if (winnerRound == 'player') {
                playerWins += 1;
                console.log("The score is Player: " + playerWins + " to " + computerWins + " :Computer");
                if (playerWins == 5) {
                    console.log("Congratulations! You win!");
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if (winnerRound == 'computer') {
                computerWins += 1;
                console.log("The score is Player: " + playerWins + " to " + computerWins + " :Computer");
                if (computerWins == 5) {
                    console.log("Oh No! The computer won!");
                    break;
                }

            }
            else if (winnerRound == 'tie' ){
                console.log("The score is Player: " + playerWins + " to " + computerWins + " :Computer");
            }
        }


    console.log("The final score is: ");
    return "Player: " + playerWins + ", Computer: " + computerWins;
}

playToFive();
```

[Click here to see it mess up the scores!](https://repl.it/BzHz/4)

eta: [click to see picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIr5h.jpg)

Comment: You forgot to include the option of the player choosing scissors and the computer choosing rock.

Comment: I can’t really reproduce your issue… what do you mean by “random increments”? Do you have a screenshot of it happening?

Comment: just to add to @Xufox
    else if(playerMove == "scissors" && computerMove == "rock") {
        winner = "computer";
    } is needed

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I linked a picture for reference

Answer (score 1):

Needing one more option under getWinner()

```
else if(playerMove == "scissors" && computerMove == "rock") { 
    winner = "computer"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than that missing branch of logic from your getWinner function for scissors (P1) vs rock (CPU), you're not outputting the results of your scores. You're returning that as a string. Just append that string to your current console output, or show it all in an alert or something.

```
console.log("The final score is... " +
    "Player: " + playerWins + ", " +
    "Computer: " + computerWins);
```

Your getWinner function could also just return an int rather than a string. 1 = player win, 0 = tie, -1 = CPU win.

Comment: I wish I wasn't so much of a noob that none of this made sense to me. Augh, I have so much to learn. Thank you for the help.